# How to resolve "_this is undefined" in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

i am trying to populate a list by getting items from a firebase database and pushing them to a list. After a lot of searching around i reached this point in my code:

```
this.angFire.database.list('/SpareParts', {
  query: {
    orderByChild: '',
    limitToFirst: this.limit  // this is a BehaviorSubject<number>(3)
  }
}).subscribe(items => items.forEach(item => function f(j) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('timeout');
    this.items.push(item);
    if (--j) f(j);
  }, 3000)
}.bind(this)(3) ));
```

Here i am grabbing only 3 items from firebase. The code does work in a way. It goes through the **setTimeout**, pushes the three items at the same time in the list and after it's done, it crashes with the error:

> _this is undefined

Before this, i was getting the error

> this is undefined

so i used the .bind function which still didn't work.

Any advise on this would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: function f(j) should be (j) => {} because the actual prevents you to have access to this

Comment: @Sorikairo By changing the function f(j)  to  (j) => {} i can't have a self-invoking function anymore, therefore i probably have to change all of that part of the code, something which i cannot seem to figure out.

Comment: @drdream100 All of this feels very fishy.  Why are you wrapping in a setTimeout at all?  And no, I don't see how you think you'd be able to re-invoke f, considering it is a callback function that is already being invoked in the first place.

Comment: @David L I forgot to mention I'm using the Ionic 2 framework. The idea is to get a few items from a Firebase db and add them to a list with a delay, resulting in a staggered fade-in animation as they're added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store this as a variable outside of your function and use that reference to refer to your component.

```
var self = this; // <-- store here
this.angFire.database.list('/SpareParts', {
  query: {
    orderByChild: '',
    limitToFirst: this.limit  // this is a BehaviorSubject<number>(3)
  }
}).subscribe(items => items.forEach(item => function f(j) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('timeout');
    self.items.push(item); // <-- use here
    if (--j) f(j);
  }, 3000)
}.bind(this)(3) ));
```

Comment: For some reason this gave me the "self is undefined" error at first. But after rebuilding the code, it's working as expected! I don't know why that happens. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @eko `const self = this;` the global variables are not updating instantly, values are changing after sometime, any suggestion?